# Definition for "power" of a tree? (Kurepa trees)

Tags: set-theory, terminology, definition

When I look at Wikipedia entries and papers online referencing Kurepa trees, the definition for a Kurepa tree includes the note that "by $\omega_1$-tree we mean a tree of power $\omega_1$ and height $\omega_1$". The height of a tree is frequently defined, but oddly enough, "power of a tree" does not seem to be.

Elsewhere in basic set theory, $\alpha$-tree means a tree of height $\alpha$ with the size of each level *strictly less* than the cardinality of $\alpha$. For these definitions to be compatible, it seems that "power of a tree is $\alpha$" would have a very strange definition: $\alpha$ = $\beta^+$ when there exists a level of the tree of maximum cardinality $\beta$, else $\alpha$ = the supremum of the cardinalities of all levels of the tree.

What does "power of a tree" actually mean, and where should I have looked to learn this definition?

Comment: Power is another word for cardinality.

Comment: (So, in particular, there is no requirement that the levels be countable.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If you are correct, the Wikipedia page must be in error: it says a Kurepa tree has _no_ uncountable levels by virtue of having uncountable power (see papers where Jech-Kunen trees are defined).

Comment: No, I agree. All I am saying is that to say that a tree has power $\kappa$ does not imply that the levels should have size less than $\kappa$. So the definition as stated is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power of a set is its cardinality. (As opposed to its power set, which is something else.) As you noticed in the comments, Kurepa trees are supposed to have countable levels, although just saying that a tree has size and height $\omega_1$ is not enough to conclude this, so the definition you quoted is incomplete as stated.

Usually the convention is that a $\kappa$-tree is a tree of height $\kappa$, all of whose levels are of size less than $\kappa$. (This implies in particular that the tree has size $\kappa$.)

By the way, if you remove from the definition of Kurepa tree the requirement that the levels be countable, you get the notion of weak Kurepa tree, which is also referred to in the literature with the name "Canadian tree".

Comment: I'm almost ready to upvote and check this but I need to do a little more research first. Jech defines "power of a set" as the name for the notation of $X^n$ (the auto-product $n$ times), and I'm still having difficulty finding that term used elsewhere to mean cardinality. Is there a basic set theory book or paper you can point me to which uses that express definition?

Comment: Oh, that's funny. What Jech defines is *a* power of a set, rather than *the* power of a set.

Comment: Found it (MathWorld)!

Comment: The term comes from Cantor, by the way.

Comment: Actually he doesn't make the error directly: the index points from "power of a set" to the definition for "a power of a set". That also comes up first in Google, but MathWorld is close behind with cardinality. I didn't look that route because I thought this was a tree-specific term like 'height', etc.

Comment: And this may be an abuse of StackEx, but on the topic of simple definition confusion: I teach CS and we prefer to define 'height' differently from set theory and graph theory (as total number of levels), because our trees are always finite and making the order-1 graph have a height of 1 allows us to include the order-0 graph in the definition of 'tree' as a recursive base-case (i.e. a data structure with no elements yet).  : )

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I wasn't aware of the difference in conventions. Thanks!